# Move multiple columns non-NA value to left column when condition is true

Tags: r, dataframe

How to convert `df` to `df_want`? When `move_left == 1`, then move the non NA values to left columns.

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~v1, ~v2, ~v3, ~v4, ~v5, ~move_left,
   1L, "a",  NA, "b",  NA, "c",          0L,
   2L, "a",  NA, "b",  NA, "c",          1L,
   3L,  NA, "a",  NA, "b",  NA,          0L,
   4L,  NA,  NA, "a",  NA,  NA,          1L,
   5L,  NA,  NA, "a",  NA, "b",          1L,
   6L, "a", "b",  NA, "c", "d",          1L
  )

df_want <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~v1, ~v2, ~v3, ~v4, ~v5, ~move_left,
   1L, "a",  NA, "b",  NA, "c",          0L,
   2L, "a", "b", "c",  NA,  NA,          1L,
   3L,  NA, "a",  NA, "b",  NA,          0L,
   4L, "a",  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,          1L,
   5L, "a", "b",  NA,  NA,  NA,          1L,
   6L, "a", "b", "c", "d",  NA,          1L
  )

df
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>      id v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    move_left
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <int>
#> 1     1 a     <NA>  b     <NA>  c             0
#> 2     2 a     <NA>  b     <NA>  c             1
#> 3     3 <NA>  a     <NA>  b     <NA>          0
#> 4     4 <NA>  <NA>  a     <NA>  <NA>          1
#> 5     5 <NA>  <NA>  a     <NA>  b             1
#> 6     6 a     b     <NA>  c     d             1

df_want
#> # A tibble: 6 × 7
#>      id v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    move_left
#>   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <int>
#> 1     1 a     <NA>  b     <NA>  c             0
#> 2     2 a     b     c     <NA>  <NA>          1
#> 3     3 <NA>  a     <NA>  b     <NA>          0
#> 4     4 a     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>          1
#> 5     5 a     b     <NA>  <NA>  <NA>          1
#> 6     6 a     b     c     d     <NA>          1
```

[image: console output]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why do the `b` and `c` move across in row 2 but not row 1?

Comment: Hi, there is a varaible `move_left` and only move when `move_left == 1`

Comment: Hi, if any answers have solved your question, you could consider accepting one of them you prefer by clicking the check mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `base` way

```r
df[df$move_left == 1, 2:6] <- t(
  apply(df[df$move_left == 1, 2:6], 1, \(x) x[order(is.na(x))])
)

df
# # A tibble: 6 × 7
#      id v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    move_left
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>     <int>
# 1     1 a     NA    b     NA    c             0
# 2     2 a     b     c     NA    NA            1
# 3     3 NA    a     NA    b     NA            0
# 4     4 a     NA    NA    NA    NA            1
# 5     5 a     b     NA    NA    NA            1
# 6     6 a     b     c     d     NA            1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer from tidyverse `tidyr::unite()` and `tidyr::separate()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

var <- c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5")

df_want2 <- df %>%
  mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>%
  filter(move_left == 1) %>%
  unite(v_all, all_of(var), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  separate(v_all, var, fill = "right") %>%
  bind_rows(df %>% mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>% filter(move_left != 1)) %>%
  arrange(row_num) %>%
  select(-row_num)

identical(df_want, df_want2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>